# Sort Array of object by keyword and value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have following array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Exam",
    "value": 27
  },
  {
    "type": "Lesson",
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "type": "Lesson",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Exam",
    "value": 67
  }
]
```

I need to display Lessons first decreased, then Exams decreased, so in the end I will have such an array:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Lesson",
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "type": "Lesson",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Exam",
    "value": 67
  },
  {
    "type": "Exam",
    "value": 27
  },
]
```

I achieved to sort it *all* by decreasing value with function `arr.sort((a,b)=>b.value-a.value))`, but I don't know how to also sort with keyword. I use React.js with TypeScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the type first and then sort by value descending.

```js
const data = [{ type: "Exam", value: 27 }, { type: "Lesson", value: 17 }, { type: "Lesson", value: 4 }, { type: "Exam", value: 67 }];

data.sort((a, b) => (b.type === 'Lesson') - (a.type === 'Lesson') || b.value - a.value);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An approach with an object for the sorting order.

```js
const
    data = [{ type: "Exam", value: 27 }, { type: "Lesson", value: 17 }, { type: "Lesson", value: 4 }, { type: "Exam", value: 67 }],
    order = { Lesson: 1, Exam: 2 };

data.sort((a, b) => order[a.type] - order[b.type] || b.value - a.value);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You should probably explain that booleans are treated as numbers in math operations (false == 0 and true == 1).

Comment: Seriously, in production development I'd consider `(b.type === 'Lesson') - (a.type === 'Lesson')`  almost a fireable offense.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a variable to store the order of the types, so that it can be easily changed in the future (e.g. if you have to add "pre-exam tests" or something similar):

```js
const input = [
  {
    "type": "Exam",
    "value": 27
  },
  {
    "type": "Lesson",
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "type": "Lesson",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Exam",
    "value": 67
  }
]

const typeOrder = ['Lesson', 'Exam'];

const output = input.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.type === b.type) return b.value - a.value;
  
  return typeOrder.indexOf(a.type) - typeOrder.indexOf(b.type);
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You can simplify that even further by making `typeOrder` an object and then: `input.sort((a, b) => typeOrder[a.type] - typeOrder[b.type] || b.value - a.value)`

Comment: but in general, your code is way better than the accepted and upvoted answer. StackOverflow is crazy sometimes.